# Why does '(a . b . c) evaluate to (b a c) in PLT-Scheme 372?

Tags: list, syntax, scheme, racket

I'm trying to understand the relations between **pair**, **cons**, **dotted tuples** and **proper list** in PLT-Scheme 372. The detailed context of my question is as follows:

After reading some textbook and doing trial-and-error, I have got the following understanding and **intuitive ideas** (I may be wrong...):

1. all lists are pairs, e.g.:

   `(pair? (list 'a 'b 'c))        => #t`
2. all conses are pairs, e.g.:

   `(pair? (cons 'a (cons 'b 'c))) => #t`
3. **some** dot-separated tuples are pairs, e.g.:

   `(pair? '(a . b))               => #t`
   `(pair? '(a . b . c))           => #t` **in Standard R5RS it's not legal syntax.**

Then I bumped into this problem: Why does '(a . b . c) evaluate to (b a c)? Where can I find a complete usage manual of **dot**?

```
'(a . b)                => (a . b)   
'(a . b . c)            => (b a c)
'(a . b . c . d)        => illegal use of `.'
'(cons 'a (cons 'b 'c)) => (a b . c)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Racket (PLT), there is a good description [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html).

Regarding the syntax `(a . b . c)` look at the bottom of the page, it's a Racket-specific reader extension designed to express typical tests like `(< 1 2)` as `(1 . < . 2)`.

Comment: And for `Scheme` it's not legal syntax.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, that's what I meant by *Racket-specific*.

Comment: Thanks! Both of you share with me better "mind path" for understanding the "dotted tuples". :)

Comment: @PIMGeek Ever thought of upgrading your version of PLT to Racket (same product, new name, more recent version)?

Comment: I have tried to toggle Racket's Programming Language to "Standard (R5RS)", and then `'(a . b . c)` evaluate to `illegal use of '.'` now!

Comment: @PIMGeek Because R5RS and R6RS are *Scheme* standards, whereas *Racket* is its own language. But the Racket *environment* implements several languages.

Comment: @uselpa - let me reconsider my decision ... I was encouraged by Paul Graham to learn Lisp as a "quick prototyping lang for exploratory programming", and then I tried arc for once - http://arclanguage.org/install , after that I chose PLT-Scheme 372 blindly...

Comment: @PIMGeek I can certainly recommend Racket, the basics are easy to learn, the environment is simple and powerful, and you can continue to truly mind-bending things if you want to. Don't hop languages in the beginning, try to learn one seriously. And Racket and Scheme are easier to learn than Common Lisp imo.

Comment: @uselpa So even if I use the latest version of Racket, I can still program in Standard R5RS without any loss (since I don't want to use ARC anymore)... How superstitious I was...

Comment: @PIMGeek Yes absolutely, it has Scheme, Racket, and some more, but not Common Lisp nor Arc.

Comment: I totally agree, in fact I had tried Lisp and then switch to Scheme because the later has way more minimal syntax and let me focus on ideas rather than language itself. :)

Comment: @PIMGeek you can program in two scheme standards in DrRacket, #!r5rs and #!r6rs and they will be faithful to the report.