# What's the behavior of double dot notation in PLT Scheme / Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm recently implementing a scheme interpreter using scheme itself. I know that single dot notation means constructing a pair or defining a lambda with multiple parameters. But then I discover that

```
'(3 . 4 . 5)
```

evaluates to

```
'(4 3 5)
```

and

```
(define (a . b . c) (displayln b) (displayln c))
(a 4 3)
```

it will print (weird that #\newline is not printed)

```
(4 3)>
```

Can somebody explain the meaning of double dot notation?

Comment: according to http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html , `(define (a . b . c) ... )` should be evaluated as `(define (b a c) ...)`. so `(a 1 2)` should raise error "_a: undefined_". Are there any function which named `a` in your source code ?

Comment: Also note that the double dot notation is a Racket extension not used in standard Scheme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does '(a . b . c) evaluate to (b a c) in PLT-Scheme 372?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816353/why-does-a-b-c-evaluate-to-b-a-c-in-plt-scheme-372)

Comment: @ymonad yeah that 'define' was my typo. Thanks so much for these comments.

Comment: In *scheme* (a language conforming to one of the standard reports) this is invalid syntax and won't work. *PLT Scheme* is not a Scheme language but an application suit. The new name is *racket*. Amongst the languages you can choose *scheme* which is the old name of *racket* which isn't a language following a standard report. Since this is `#!racket` specific it has nothing to do with [tag:scheme]

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html

> If the reader finds three or more data between the 
>   matching parentheses, and if a pair of delimited .s 
>   surrounds any other than the first and last elements, 
>   the result is a list containing the element surrounded 
>   by .s as the first element, followed by the others in 
>   the read order. This convention supports a kind of 
>   infix notation at the reader level.

Racket provides the double dot syntax for the purpose of infix function calls:

```
(2 . + . 3) => 5
```